# CustomScore and biggest value from all docs

Tags: lucene, elasticsearch

Hi now i have `custom_score "_score + ((parseInt(doc.ad_when.value) - oldestAd) / doc.ad_since.value) * 2"`. Is possible to use in custom score biggest value from all docs. I want that oldestAd was from all searched data. MySql have function MAX. In MySql it will be easy.

Example:
 in all docs i have popularity field and i want use biggest value from all docs to customscore. is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it can be only done in two steps. First, you need to retrieve the first record from the list sorted by `ad_when.value` or find the `oldestAd` value using facets. Then you can use this value in the custom score. I would suggest making `oldestAd` a script parameter to prevent elasticsearch from parsing the script on every request.

Comment: No possible to make everything in one request? :-O It will be cool. Example can be in solr, because engine it's same.

Comment: The biggest challenge of doing something like this in one request comes from the distributed nature of elasticsearch. To implement it correctly, elasticsearch would have to 1) send a broadcast request to all shards and find oldestAd among all shards 2) execute search request on all shards with the oldestAd, merge the results and then 3) fetch top records. The current implementation doesn't have any way of doing 1) before 2) and 3). You can implement something like this as an elasticsearch plugin though.